# How to secure all pages in folder with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, wicket

The application has four roles and four matching folders containing pages. One extra folder contains pages shared by multiple roles. Currently, there are no restrictions. A tester found that a page could be accessed directly by copying a bookmark for use with one role and pasting it when logged in with a different role.

The use of Spring Security is minimal. There is a enum for the roles and a matching table in the database. Users can have multiple roles, selecting one when they log in.

I have seen examples like this, which would go into out spring-security.xml file.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/events/" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> 
</http>
```

I would like to code it like this:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/administrator/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')"/> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/client/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')"/> 
</http>
```

The code that contain the role of the logged in user is defined as:

```
public class LMSSession extends WebSession
```

Is there a way of implementing this using Wicket (7.9)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Security you have normally a class for Spring security configuration

Here a link for exemple use https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

and check section CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and the method

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll() // #4
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // #6
        .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
        .and()
    .formLogin()  // #8
        .loginUrl("/login") // #9
        .permitAll(); // #5
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Spring Security's HttpSecurity (or its XML equivalent) or Wicket's IAuthorizationStrategy to accomplish this.

It you mount your pages according to the user roles as `/client/page1` and `/client/page2` then the Spring Security snippet in your question should do it (I prefer the Java Config style, so I am not 100% certain that the XML is complete!).

But if you don't want to expose the roles in the urls then using wicket-auth-roles's `@AuthorizeInstantiation` will do it easily too.
wicket-examples has a good [demo](https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/51d9e533dc3a45183210a1f4852851b485f02ea3/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/authorization) about it!

Comment: It worked for pages that I passed with `MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.authorize(..class.., "role")` but I would prefer not to do that. The other pages did not call `hasAnyRole`.